# Python 3.x: I can't use PyQt4 on PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pyqt4

I'm doing a PyQt tutorial and I want to do everything on PyCharm, but I can't make it work in this IDE.

This is what I've done so far:

1. I have a Python version that's 3.6, 36 bits. My OS is Windows 10 64 bits.
2. I downloaded the whl file from this website ([here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4), the PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl file) and installed it later with pip.
3. Checked for the __ init __.py file and see if its in the proper folder (site-packages).

When I try to import it from PyCharm, I get this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```

> Cannot find reference QtCore in __ init __.py
>
> Cannot find reference QtGui in __ init __.py

And both files ***are*** in the PyQt4 folder. Searching for several blogs and StackOverflow posts with similar problems, many suggested to create a virtual environment. I did that in PyCharm in "Settings". I don't know if letting PyCharm create the virtualenv is enough... or do I need to do something else?

I could just switch to Eclipse or use something that doesn't give me any trouble, but I'd like to stick to PyCharm because I like it. So if you have any suggestion to make this work, I'll be more than glad to know.

Thanks in advance!